# Undefined reference to WinMain@16 - with SDL

Tags: c, reference, undefined, sdl

I'm getting an error: undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'
I struggled to correctly install SDL, but I think I got it now. Still I'm getting this error.
Maybe someone can help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int a=0;

    printf("%d", a);

    return 0;
}
```

compiler linkings:
-mingw, -SDLmain, -SDL

Thanks

Comment: `WinMain@16` isn't an error. Please add the _full_ error message.

Comment: sorry, the error is: "undefined reference to 'winMain@16'

Comment: please share your build command.  I suspect you're missing SDL2main library.

Comment: I added them to my post

Comment: thank you for clarifying.  please check those libraries match what is returned by `sdl-config --libs`. if that matches, you might try `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` before including SDL.h.

Comment: Thank you very much! #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED made it compile!

Comment: Looks to me that you haven't solved your libraries problem at all and the moment you use first SDL function it will backfire. `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` presumes you know what you're doing and you should at the very least also do `SDL_SetMainReady()` call if you go that way (and *not* link with `SDL2main`). What's your compiler/linker? What's full compile/link command and its output?

Comment: Presumambly you are linking your program as a GUI program. These have `WinMain()` instead of `main()` as the main function.